# Isometry group of a Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

I'm having trouble dealing with the following question : what is the isomety group of $\mathbf{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ viewed as a Lie group with its Killing form ? For the record, its Killing form is the push forward of the determinant on $\mathbf{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$. I'm almost sure that the component of the identity is $\mathbf{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R}) \times \mathbf{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ acting by right and left multiplication, but i think i don't know enough theory to show it.

Thank you for looking at my problem

Comment: I think we had a similar question on Mathoverflow a while ago. Maybe you will find information there.

Comment: i checked but i didn't find an answer

Comment: Robert Bryant gave an actual algorithm to compute isometry groups of homogeneous spaces here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/75742/isometry-group-of-a-homogeneous-space, at least. In your case, you have to take $H=(e)$.